# GROUP_CONCAT() in MySQL not working while inserting value selecting from an another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to insert the **ids separated by commas** from one table to another with where clause. The **SELECT** statement is working fine but while inserting for the *specified keyword* it's returning only **1** id.

My table structure:
**TABLE 1**

```
     id                               property_id                                                 keyword
(auto-increment) (separated by commas from table 2 where keyword matches)  (matched keyword with the description column in table 1 with like clause)
```

**TABLE 2**

```
id    property_name       city      country   property_address  property_description
1   Ashish JK Apartments Bangalore  India       Thubarahalli    A Tranquil - Soul Inspiring abode is just waiting for you. Come make the Most of it. 2 BHK Ashish J K Apartment: Total No. of Flats in the Project - 216 A house is the starting point of a new journey through life. The house becomes a reflection of ourselves because we base our lives around it. We see our lives pass by and our children grow up. And all these memories accumulate and make our house a home. It has been designed keeping us as individuals in mind. We all are different. We have our own unique sensibility that is why when we built Aashish J K Apartments we thought of it as a canvas, a canvas you could paint your life on. we did that by building a house that requires, minimum maintenance, with all the systems has been designed to work in a harmonious manner that ensures you a get a good night's sleep, every night Aashish J K Apartments: Seated Between Marathalli and Whitefield, an area that is fast escalating in the property market. Aashish J K apartment is indeed a wise investment to make from the business point of view. It shares its neighborhood with ITPL, Oracle, IGate, HUL, AAI and Other IT Parks located in a very prime place. This location today is a seat of contention for many of Bangalore's real estate developers. One thing that all of us can agree on, is that we all want value for money, and we are sure you would love to know just what Aashish J K Apartments would offer to you and your loved ones within your Pocket limits.
2   Aban Essence         Bangalore  India       Sarjapur Road   A home is not just a structure, it is a part of a flourishing future and the roof that keeps the present intact. We understand this well and hence the apartments are equipped with all the necessary amenities for a family, like swimming pools, gym, club houses, jogging track, garden etc. Along with this beauty are the ample number of trees and plants in the properties. At aban you will find a happy and a peaceful living with luxury and security
```

So, in **Table 1** I basically want where *TABLE 1* actually have 7000 data:

```
id   property_id   keyword
1    1,2           Bangalore
```

**I've tried:**

```
insert into TABLE_1(property_id,keyword) 
SELECT group_concat(id separator ','),'Bangalore' from TABLE_2 AS a
WHERE a.description like '%Bangalore%' OR a.city like '%Banglore%' group by 'Bangalore';
```

The individual **SELECT** statement is working fine and returning proper result,
but when I use the **INSERT** statement it's just returning the **TABLE_2** with the first id matching with the keyword. i.e:

**TABLE_2 after running the query**:

```
id property_id keyword
1  1           Bangalore
```

Now how to get the ***Comma Separated ids*** in the property_id column like what the **SELECT** statement returns.
I'm stuck with this since yesterday and found only **UPDATE** things like such. but nothing with insert in proper.
I know **WHERE** clause works first then **GROUP_CONCAT()**  but how to get such results with **INSERT** also?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of the property_id field in the target table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1(property_id, keyword)
( 
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id separator ','), 'Bangalore' FROM TABLE_2
    WHERE description LIKE '%Bangalore%' OR city LIKE '%Banglore%' 
)
```

Comment: The result is still the same. :( It's returning with one id only

Comment: change you table1 property_id type from integer to string

Comment: Thanks brother you saved all my effort. I'm marking it as answered. Yet can you please explain why is it not working for integer?

Comment: because your comma-separated list is a string. integer "is only digits" no commas allowed there :) sory, bad English

Comment: No issues I got your point. So basically just because of the commas it's behaving like a string right? Will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
insert into TABLE_1(property_id,keyword) 
SELECT group_concat(id),'Bangalore' from TABLE_2 AS a
WHERE a.description like '%Bangalore%' OR a.city like '%Banglore%'
```

Comment: I've tried that too.. Here also the respective **SELECT** statement works fine i.e  `SELECT group_concat(id),'Bangalore' from TABLE_2 AS a
WHERE a.description like '%Bangalore%' OR a.city like '%Banglore%' ` but while inserting it's not providing the _comma separated id_ but returning only the **first** id matching the keyword.

Comment: what is the datatype of property id of table1?

Comment: property_id is **bigint(20)**

Comment: How can bigint accept a comma separated value? It should be varchar(8000) and it should wok fine